# What is the difference between pascal_case and first_word_upper in .editorconfig

Tags: .net, visual-studio, editorconfig

I am working on my `.editorconfig` file in visual studio and notice that when i use the `pascal_case` there is no difference with the `first_word_upper`.
Shouldn't `pascal_case` also check whether `_` is as a word separator?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it is `ThisIsPascalCase`, whereas `Thisisfirstwordupper`.

Comment: I would say so too but for the editorconfig there is no difference then?

Comment: I think there are different rules for whether `_` is allowed as a separator in the identifier or not.

Comment: In that case what is the difference in rules between PascalCase and Firstwordupper? And do you perhaps know that rule?